# Kubernetes with 0 pods using EKS or Fargate

Tags: kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

Hi is it possible to have the replica as 0 to 2 or more and when the service is being accessed, then it will scale up to 1 or max replicas given using EKS or Fargate? This means that the service will be down and only when it is accessed, then it automatically scales up at least to 1?

It's kind of serverless concept, but is it possible using EKS or Fargate?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with [`autoscaling/v2beta2`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics) where scaling condition can be defined on basis of custom metrics.

Also there event based scaling tool ([keda](https://keda.sh/docs/2.0/scalers/prometheus/)) which is pretty handy. You can use `prometheus` scaler type to scale pods based on `http_requests_total` count.

https://keda.sh/docs/2.0/scalers/prometheus/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Kubernetes without add-ons.

There are a few add-ons for Kubernetes that allow such behavior. There is a trade-off, in that it can add *latency* when serving requests.

Two good alternatives (but I doubt that they work on Fargate):

- [Knative](https://knative.dev/)
- [Keda](https://keda.sh/)

Comment: Knative on Fargate definitely "works" albeit it is to be seen whether it's something that I'd suggest using: https://github.com/mreferre/knative-on-fargate